# How do I use pymysql with gevent and django-celery?

Tags: python, mysql, django, celery, eventlet

I put the following in my manage.py (using django-celery 3.0.21):

```
import eventlet
pymysql = eventlet.import_patched('pymysql')
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

And I get the following error when I try to start django or celery:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 115, in install_as_MySQLdb
    sys.modules["MySQLdb"] = sys.modules["_mysql"] = sys.modules["pymysql"]
KeyError: 'pymysql'
```

Basically I really want to use celery with eventlet but I need a "greenable" Python MySQL library for this.

Comment: `gevent` and `eventlet` are two different libraries. Which do you wish to use?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question had the wrong title. I wanted to use eventlet because that's what Celery supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, that looks like a bug in `eventlet.import_patched()`, I've opened an issue [1] in bug tracker.

You can use the following code:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
# everything below is patched to be green

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

[1] Related Eventlet issue https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/81